# Convert string to number without built in functions

Tags: c#

I'm told to implement fucntion which takes string as a parameter and returns int. Here is how i implemented, but the question is that my implementation is ugly and would like to see other implementations of this function. According to conditions you're not allowed to use built in fucntions such tryParse, parse, or something what does all the job for you.
My implementation:

```
private static int StringToNumber(string str)
    {
        int number = 0;
        if (str.Contains('-'))
        {
            foreach (var character in str)
            {
                if (character == '-')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                number += character - '0';
                number *= 10;
            }
            number *= (-1);
            number /= 10;
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (var character in str)
            {
                number *= 10;
                number += character - '0';
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Esthetics aside, your function arguably doesn't work as advertised. It parses `Hello, world!` to `264978313`, `---` to `0`, `12.34` to `11834` and `123456789012` to `-1097262572`, for example. I'd start with writing up tests first and arranging your implementation to pass those; the examples I've given would be good to include.

Comment: Your separate negative is overkill.  Simplify and verify the input.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as it is somewhat open-ended and has not necessarily a single correct answer.

Comment: Don't forget to include range checks. No need to even start parsing a string that cannot possibly represent an integer in bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the approach following approach to solve this as well.

```
    private static int StringToInt(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) || str.Length == 0)
        {
            //invalid input, do something
            return 0;
        }
        var num = 0;
        var sign = 1;
        if (str[0] == '-')
        {
            sign = -1;
            str = str.Substring(1);
        }
        foreach (var c in str)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '0':
                    num = (num * 10);
                    break;

                case '1':
                    num = (num * 10) + 1;
                    break;

                case '2':
                    num = (num * 10) + 2;
                    break;

                case '3':
                    num = (num * 10) + 3;
                    break;

                case '4':
                    num = (num * 10) + 4;
                    break;

                case '5':
                    num = (num * 10) + 5;
                    break;

                case '6':
                    num = (num * 10) + 6;
                    break;

                case '7':
                    num = (num * 10) + 7;
                    break;

                case '8':
                    num = (num * 10) + 8;
                    break;

                case '9':
                    num = (num * 10) + 9;
                    break;

                default:
                    //do something else or ignore
                    break;
            }
        }
        return num * sign;
    }
```

Comment: Rather than a massive switch statement, you should be able to subtract the numeric value of `'0'` (48) from the character to determine the numeric value of the character checking whether it's valid (0<= value <= 9)

Comment: I am with you on that one but this is just an alternative way which can be easy for some other people to quickly understand. Subtracting '0' will require someone to understand ASCII before following the solution. Plus, I do not know how the machine handles the subtracting of ASCII chars in terms of performance.

Comment: OP has already done this in their implementation: `number += character - '0'`

Comment: With switch statement you can handle illegal characters (non numeric), and throw exception if you will. With ASCII subtraction you may get unexpected results, like subtracting `'a' - '0'` will give you `49`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant combining OP's char subtraction solution and @sitholewb solution, that is somewhat optimized.

```
public static int StringToIntCharSubtraction(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    {
        //invalid input, do something
        return 0;
    }

    var num = 0;
    var sign = 1;
    int i = 0;

    if (str[0] == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        i = 1;
    }

    while (i < str.Length)
    {
        int currentNum = (str[i] - '0');

        if (currentNum > 9 || currentNum < 0)
        {
            //do something else or ignore
            continue;
        }

        num = (num * 10) + currentNum;
        i++;
    }

    return num * sign;
}
```

If you are worried about performance here is benchmark.

```
|                       Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio | Rank |
|----------------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|-----:|
|   StringToIntCharSubtraction |  6.310 ns | 0.0637 ns | 0.0565 ns |  0.44 |    1 |
|            StringToIntSwitch | 13.824 ns | 0.3083 ns | 0.2884 ns |  0.96 |    2 |
|                    int.Parse | 14.345 ns | 0.0883 ns | 0.0782 ns |  1.00 |    3 |
```

You can even drop the first one to 3 ns if you remove the validations, but it seems too risky for me.